# Invert function in C is not working. Bitwise operators

Tags: c

I am implementing a C function `unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)`
that is returning x with the n bits that begin at position p inverted, leaving the others unchanged.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n);

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", invert(11111111, 5, 4));
    printf("%u\n", invert(10, 2, 2));

    return 0;
}

unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{   
    return x^(~(~0<<n)<<p+1-n);
}
```

This is what I got so far and if I'm tracing the function through it should be right, but I keep getting 11111163 for the first test and 12 for the second test.

Comment: Explain the logic behind your function please (in the process, you'll probably figure out where you're wrong)

Comment: are 11111111 and 10 supposed to be binary? I'm pretty sure c doesn't support binary literals... try 0xFF and 0x2 for those numbers.

Comment: `11111111` is a decimal integer, not binary. You need to pass in a hex value and convert that.  Like `0xFF` (11111111 in binary)

Comment: `11111111` is not a binary value - it is a decimal value. There are no binary literals in C. The closest you'd get is either octal (eg. `0377`) or hexadecimal (eg. `0xFF`). Furthermore, bit positions (as in what `p` supposedly signifies) are usually counted from the right (or least significant) bit, which is at position 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your program is working. Only thing you have to do is express the number in binary.

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n); 

int main()
{
    printf("%x\n", invert(0b11111111, 5, 4));
    printf("%x\n", invert(0b10, 2, 2));

return 0;

}

unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)

{   
     return x^(~(~0<<n)<<p+1-n);
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: this helps, but is there a way to return an binary number?

Comment: a number is a number. it depends on how you print it on the screen.
If you want to print it in a binary format, you need something like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)